# Watch change in folder using windows API, Function being called two times, instead of one

Tags: excel, vba, directory

having problem in `VBA` project, in which it watch a folder, as file change notifies using `Windows API`. The issue I'm facing is that the `WatchChangeAction` function is being called twice for a single file change.

I'm wondering if my logic is correct in `Command1_Click`. Please suggest the alternative approaches to handle these notifications more reliably, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

```
Dim hChangeHandle As Long
Dim hWatched As Long
Dim terminateFlag As Long
         
Private Const INFINITE As Long = &HFFFFFFFF
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME As Long = &H1
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME As Long = &H2
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES As Long = &H4
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE As Long = &H8
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE As Long = &H10
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS As Long = &H20
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION As Long = &H40
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY As Long = &H100
Private Const FILE_NOTIFY_FLAGS = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES Or _
                                 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME Or _
                                 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindFirstChangeNotification Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "FindFirstChangeNotificationA" _
   (ByVal lpPathName As String, _
    ByVal bWatchSubtree As Long, _
    ByVal dwNotifyFilter As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindCloseChangeNotification Lib "kernel32" _
   (ByVal hChangeHandle As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindNextChangeNotification Lib "kernel32" _
   (ByVal hChangeHandle As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
   (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

#Else
    MsgBox "API will not work, VBA issue"
#End If

Private Const WAIT_OBJECT_0 As Long = &H0
Private Const WAIT_ABANDONED As Long = &H80
Private Const WAIT_IO_COMPLETION As Long = &HC0
Private Const WAIT_TIMEOUT As Long = &H102
Private Const STATUS_PENDING As Long = &H103

Private Sub Command1_Click()

   Dim watchPath As String
   Dim watchStatus As Long
   
   terminateFlag = False
   Command1.Enabled = False
   
                                      watchPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
               hWatched = WatchCreate(watchPath, FILE_NOTIFY_FLAGS)
    Label2 = "Watching of folder: " & watchPath
   
   watchStatus = WatchDirectory(hWatched, 100)
   
   If watchStatus = 0 Then
       WatchChangeAction watchPath
       Do
         watchStatus = WatchResume(hWatched, 100)
         If watchStatus = -1 Then
            Label2.Caption = "Watching has been terminated for " & watchPath
         Else
            WatchChangeAction watchPath
            Label2.Caption = "The watched directory has been changed again."
         End If
       Loop While watchStatus = 0
   Else
      Label2.Caption = "Watching has been terminated for " & watchPath
   End If
   
End Sub

Private Function WatchCreate(lpPathName As String, flags As Long) As Long

  'FindFirstChangeNotification members:
  '
  '  lpPathName: folder to watch
  '  bWatchSubtree:
  '     True = watch specified folder and its sub folders
  '     False = watch the specified folder only
  '  flags: OR'd combination of the FILE_NOTIFY_ flags to apply
  
   WatchCreate = FindFirstChangeNotification(lpPathName, False, flags)

End Function

Private Function WatchDirectory(hWatched As Long, interval As Long) As Long

  'Poll the watched folder.
  'The Do..Loop will exit when:
  '   r = 0, indicating a change has occurred
  '   terminateFlag = True, set by the WatchDelete routine
  
   Dim r As Long
   
   Do
   
      r = WaitForSingleObject(hWatched, interval)
      DoEvents
   
   Loop While r <> 0 And terminateFlag = False
   
   WatchDirectory = r
   
End Function


Private Function WatchResume(hWatched As Long, interval) As Boolean

   Dim r As Long
   
   r = FindNextChangeNotification(hWatched)
   
   Do
      
      r = WaitForSingleObject(hWatched, interval)
      DoEvents
   
   Loop While r <> 0 And terminateFlag = False
   
   WatchResume = r
   
End Function


Private Sub WatchChangeAction(fPath As String)

   Dim fName As String
   
   On Error Resume Next
   With List1
   
      .Clear

      fName = Dir(fPath & Application.PathSeparator & "*.csv")
   
      If Len(fName) > 0 Then
   
         .AddItem "path: " & vbTab & fPath
         .AddItem "file: " & vbTab & fName
         .AddItem "size: " & vbTab & FileLen(fPath & Application.PathSeparator & fName)
         .AddItem "attr: " & vbTab & GetAttr(fPath & Application.PathSeparator & fName)
      
        'M_byMBA_2 fPath & Application.PathSeparator & fName
        Beep
   
      End If
   End With

End Sub
```